# Teams Task Module from Adpative Card Button Click

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

With new Bot Framework V4 introduced, where should we catch the Task Module response in the Bot. Right now, just have the following method in the Bot class:

`public async onTurn(context: TurnContext): Promise<any>`

And as per the Documentation cannot use the onInvoke method for calling the Task Module from Adaptive Card button click :https://github.com/wictorwilen/botbuilder-teams-messagingextensions.

Please suggest how can we display the Task Module result on Adaptive Card button click.

Thanks!

Comment: Please take a look at [Teams Task module](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module). Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for sharing the link. I am using Messaging Extension to show Adaptive Card onQuery and then want to invoke a Task Module from the Adaptive Card. Could you please share some example on that in either typescript or js. I have looked through the js example of shared link. Thanks

Comment: I have added the below code in the MessagingExtensionBot class and now atleast I am not getting the error of 'Not Impleted' for Task Module - `onInvoke: async(context: TurnContext): Promise<InvokeResponse>` under activityProc.invokeActivityHandler. But the still the Task Module is not returning the actual result. How should we implement the  task: continue response:  `task: {"type": "continue","value": {"title": "Title","height": 800,
"width": 1000,
"url": `url`,
"fallbackUrl": `fallbackurl`,
                                },
}` Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at TaskModuleContinueReponse  ,Task = new TaskModuleContinueResponse
                {
                    Value = new TaskModuleTaskInfo()
                    {
                        Card = new Attachment
                        {
                            Content = card/url,
                            ContentType = .ContentType,
                        },
                        Height = 500,
                        Width = 600,
                        Title = "Hello world...",
                    },

Comment: You're question is missing a bit of context. However,  If you're using V4 in .Net core you have a "TeamsInvokeActivityHandler" which is the one handling invoke requests for the task module. 

This is a good example explaining that:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-dotnet/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams.MessagingExtensionBot